# Subset Sum Problem with constraints and multiple inputs

Tags: python, constraints, subset-sum

I'm trying to figure out a way to implement in python a subset sum problem with the constraint that the numbers in the Fixed variable have to always be included.

For Example:
given the following lists:

Variable = [1,2,3,4,5]

Fixed = [6,7]

Target = [20]

I need to know which combination of numbers in Variable comes closest to the target 20 (but doesn't exceed it), at the same time the numbers in the Fixed list have to always be included in the sum.

Any combination of values in Variable + all values in Fixed that is closest to Target

if there are multiple combinations that match the Target exactly or come very close (having the same value) then I'm ok just looking at the first combination that matches the criteria.

In the example above the solution should be
6+7+3+4 = 20

I have tried the below example which should return 3 but I get None. Admittedly I'm new to python and any explanation of where I went wrong would be highly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

Fixed = pd.Series([3,2])
Variable = pd.Series([15,1,4,6,3,10])
Target = 8


def subsetsum(Variable,Target,Fixed):

    if Target == 0 or Target < 1:
        return None
    elif len(Variable) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        if Variable.iloc[0] == Target:
            return [Variable.iloc[0]]
        else:
            with_v = subsetsum(Variable.iloc[1:], (Target - (Variable.iloc[0]+Fixed.sum())),Fixed)
            if with_v:
                return [Variable.iloc[0]] + with_v
            else:
                return subsetsum(Variable.iloc[1:],Target,Fixed)
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: I have edited my original  question with the code I was using. Thank you!

Comment: This is  not a pandas problem at all.  You can use `itertools.permutations` to return all subsets of your `Variable` list, and then its just a simple `sum` to compare that against `20-sum(Fixed)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution without using pandas, which does not help you at all here:

```
import itertools

Fixed = [3,2]
Variable = [15,1,4,6,3,10]
Target = 8

def findAllSubsets( array, target ):
    answers = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(array,i+1):
            if sum(subset) == target:
                answers.append( subset )
    return answers

print(findAllSubsets( Variable, Target-sum(Fixed)))
```

The output is [3], which is the only answer for your input set.